# HTACCESS - Arquivo Externo

Tags: htaccess

Tenho um arquivo .htaccess, mas se eu tiver um arquivo fora da pasta, ele não me permite acesso... E gostaria que permitisse:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|site|assets|fonts|images|css|js|administrar|entrada|docs|system)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Este arquivo está na raiz, onde o arquivo que eu quero exibir também está, para que eu consiga exibir tenho que remover o htaccess, mas preciso dele para gerenciar o administrador.

Edição:
Este arquivo está na raiz do site, e precisava que na raiz do site tivesse um arquivo php, qualquer nome... e por conta disso não acessava. Mas já deu certo. E postei a resposta.

Comment: Tua pergunta e respostas não fazem sentido, acesso fora, ou acesso pelo arquivo .php? Recomendo que edite a pergunta, por enquanto votei por fechar, quando terminar a edição voto pra reabrir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborei da seguinte forma e deu certo!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione em seu .htaccess a entrada abaixo para permitir acesso ao arquivo `arquivoPermitido.php`

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<Files "arquivoPermitido.php">
   Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Não deu certo dessa forma.

Comment: Poderia testar adicionando as linhas **Order deny,allow** e **Deny from all** no início do arquivo por favor? Editei o código da resposta com essas duas novas linhas.

Comment: Sim adicionei, mas dá acesso proibido em tudo...

Comment: E se você deixar no seu arquivo .htacces somente o código que eu coloquei na resposta?

Comment: Acesso Proibido!

Comment: Mesmo reiniciando o Apache? Apenas editar o arquivo pode não pegar as alterações se não reiniciar o servidor. Desculpe a insistência, mas é que essa solução funcionou para essa mesma pergunta em inglês. Às vezes pode te ajudar também: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19623286/1639385

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Fiz assim e deu certo

Comment: Legal. Problema resolvido :)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26248/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-ulysses-alves).